# Sticky Header position multi language site

Tags: html, css, wordpress, header

I messed up something on a multilingual site in the css (?) files so that the header of repucom.net/de , repucom.net/fr and repucom.net/pt is no longer on the top. On the english and japanese sites, repucom.net and repucom.jp, it stays on top.

I have no clue how I messed this up and would gratefully appreciate any help whereabout I should start digging into.

Fiddle for the working site (not sure if I did this right, if I should change anything - please let me know): http://jsfiddle.net/bn85y/1/

Fiddle for the non-working site: http://jsfiddle.net/zBbw5/

Html Example non working site:

```
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<title>REPUCOM</title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://repucom.net/de/wp-content/themes/repucom-de/style.css" />
```

```
<div id="header">

    <div id="branding">

            </div><!--  #branding -->

</div><!-- #header-->
```

Comment: Please create [fiddles](http://jsfiddle.net) for both the working and the non-working sites. You need to show some effort to get help.

Comment: Tried to adjust question to meet standards for non off-topic - if anything else is missing, please let me know.

Comment: The problem was that some files called by the header were not in UTF-8 without BOM. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save your file encoded as as UTF-8 without BOM, and that's gonna solve the issue. You'll probably find that option in your text editor. 
For example if you're a **Sublime Text** user you'll find the option going to File>Save with Encoding>UTF-8.

You can always detect this kind of things running the W3C validator:
http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=repucom.net%2Ffr

Comment: No it's not going to fix it. Yes, it's an issue but it doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: so what do you think I should look into more deeply @Christian?

Comment: It's a very common issue generated by files encoded with BOM. If you inspect the DOM you'll see the parts of the <head> inside the <body> but if you see the source code they're not. @groeter, have you had any problem doing what I suggest you to do? I see your file stills having this BOM encoding. If you're not sure how to do it in your text editor just google "save without BOM -name of your text editor-" As soon as you do that the white space is going to disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Please, check that right after the opening `<body>` tag there is an empty string. If you remove it, the header will position itself correctly.

Comment: Thanks for you response jalba. There is an empty string on the repucom.net site as well - so that is probably not it.

Comment: I'm using Chrome developer tools. The element view. With that tool you can clearly see an empty text node right below the <body> opening tag, that it's just present on the broken sites. Furthermore, taking a deeper look into this, on this tool I can see the <header> as empty, and everything that should be on the header as being render in the body (metatags, css links, and script tags. Again this only happens on the broken sites. On repucom.net I can see the header correctly rendered.

Comment: Yes, thank you - I can see that now. Can you give me a hint how I could change that - is it a CSS problem? I am not able to find the files in which I can remove the empty string. Thanks a lot

Comment: It seems to me that it may be a problem of the template or template engine that it's being used to render the page.

Comment: The problem was that some files called by the header were not in UTF-8 without BOM. Thanks for your help anyway!